# Create symlink from the contents of a file

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

Due to an inefficient workflow where I have to copy directories between a Linux machine and a windows machine. The directories contain symlinks which (after copying Linux>Windows>Linux) contain the link in plaintext (eg `foobar.C` contains the text `../../../Foo/Bar/foobar.C`)

Is there an efficient way to recreate the symlinks from the contents of the file recursively for a complete directory?

I have tried:

```
find . | xargs ln -s ??A?? ??B?? && mv ??B?? ??A??
```

where I really have no idea how to populate the variables, but `??A??` should be the symlink's destination from the file and `??B??` should be the name of the file with the suffix `_temp` appended.

Comment: You mean, find all files which contain a single line with the name of an existing file, and replace those with a symlink to that file?  That shouldn't be hard.  What have you tried?

Comment: After copying from linux to windows what do these files contain? Are they copying as shortcuts? Or is that when the change is made to the plaintext name of the file?

Comment: After copying to windows the file contains the path of the symlink. For example:

foobar.C:
../../foo/bar/foobar.C

@triplee: I have tried:
find . | xargs ln -s #this is where i have no clue, should be destination from file# #name of file appended with _temp# && mv #name of temp#  #name of file#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that all the files contain a symlink, it's not very hard.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -r 0 sh -c '
 for f; do ln -s "$(cat "$f")" "${f}_temp" && mv "${f}_temp" "$f"; done' _
```

The `_` dummy argument is necessary because the second argument to `sh -c` is used to populate `$0` in the subshell.  The shell itself is necessary because you cannot directly pass multiple commands to `xargs`.

The `-print0` and corresponding `xargs -0` are a GNU extension to correctly cope with tricky file names.  See the `find` manual for details.

I would perhaps add a simple verification check before proceeding with the symlinking; for example, if `grep -cm2 .` on the file returns 2, skip the file (it contains more than one line of text).  If you can be more specific (say, all the symlinks begin with `../`) by all means be more specific.